# Group array of hashes by a given key and accumulate values

Tags: ruby

The source (already ordered properly):

```
rows = [{"key"=>[2012, 10]}, {"key"=>[2012, 9]}, {"key"=>[2011, 7]}]
```

Desired result:

```
[[2012, [10, 9]], [2011, [7]]]
```

Comment: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/614/do-not-prematurely-accept-answers?cb=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows.map {|row| row.values.flatten}.inject({}) {|h,r| h[r[0]].nil? ? h[r[0]] = [r[1]] : h[r[0]] << r[1];h }.to_a
# [[2012, [10, 9]], [2011, [7]]]
```

or

```
rows.map {|row| row.values.flatten}.inject({}) {|h,r| h[r[0]] ||= []; h[r[0]] << r[1];h }.to_a
# [[2012, [10, 9]], [2011, [7]]]
```

Comment: I don't see why inject is necessary here, group_by or chunk + map should be enough. It seems you're using inject to do a manual grouping?

Answer (score 2):

Since the data is pre-ordered, we can use `chunk` instead of `group_by`:

```
rows.chunk { |h| h.values.first[0] }.map do |year, hs| 
  [year, hs.map { |h| h.values.first[1] }]
end
#=> [[2012, [10, 9]], [2011, [7]]]
```