# Group Array of Hashes by Key followed by values

Tags: ruby

Assuming I have the following dataset

```
[ 
  {
    :name => "sam",
    :animal => "dog",
    :gender => "male"
  }, {
    :name => "max",
    :animal => "cat",
    :gender => "female"
  }, {
    :name => "joe",
    :animal => "snake",
    :gender => "male"
  }    
]
```

How would you group the array of hashes to:

```
{
  :name => ["sam", "max", "joe"]
  :animal => ["dog", "cat", "snake"]
  :gender => ["male", "female", "male"]
}
```

I've read similar articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010416/group-array-of-hashes-by-a-given-key-and-accumulate-values) and [Group array of hashes by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17513015/group-array-of-hashes-by-key)

However, most examples return the values as increment counts where I'm looking for actual separate values.

My attempt

```
keys = []
values = []

arr.each do |a|
  a.each do |k, v|
    keys << k
    #this is where it goes wrong and where I'm stuck at
    values << v
  end
end

keys = keys.uniq
```

I understand where I went wrong is how I'm trying to segment the values. Any direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input.reduce { |e, acc| acc.merge(e) { |_, e1, e2| [*e2, *e1] } }
#⇒ {:name=>["sam", "max", "joe"],
#   :animal=>["dog", "cat", "snake"],
#   :gender=>["male", "female", "male"]}
```

Comment: This is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: if source is `[{a: 1, b:2}, {a:2}]` then result will be `{:a=>[1, 2], :b=>2}`. Unique keys are not wrapped to array in this case.

Comment: @AlexKojin so what? There is no hint in the OP on how this particular case should be handled.

Comment: @mudasobwa just notice, because in a real code you will need to consider this. Of course, this is best answer.

Answer (score 1):

few more approaches

```
data.each_with_object({}){ |i,r| i.each{ |k,v| (r[k] ||= []) << v } }
data.flat_map(&:to_a).each_with_object({}){ |(k,v), r| (r[k] ||= []) << v }
data.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).inject({}){ |r, (k,v)| r[k] = v.map(&:last); r }
```

Comment: `%i|name animal gender|.each_with_object({}) { |key, acc| acc[key] = input.map { |e| e[key] } }` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa too specific :)

Comment: Also, consider using `input.flat_map(&:to_a)` instead of `input.map(&:to_a).flatten(1)`. Also, there must be a solution with `transpose` but I can’t get to it.

Comment: @mudasobwa that's nice!